# How to find the length and breadth of a rectangle in an image using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following image generated from values I had recorded. I had converted the values into a scaled image and then had resized it to 36 x 52 image.

[image]

This image shows the upscaled version of the values that I had used. What i need to do is calculate the length and breadth of the shape filled with green color. The following figure shows what I want.

[image]

I have converted the image to binary and then tried using regionprops for calculating the length and breadth using the following code.

```
     B = im2bw(A);
     B1 = double(A);
     Props = regionprops(B1,'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength');
```

Instead of getting the dimensions of the highlighted regions I have obtained all the areas with a binary value 1.

[image]

I had obtained the length and breadth of the green areas as well as yellow/orange areas. I get the following image if i convert rgb to binary image, whereas what i want is only the centre rectangle's dimensions.

[image]

The dimensions that I have obtained includes the two other white regions in the sides. I should either eliminate them or calculate only the dimensions of the rectangle How do I proceed with finding the area it. Or are there any other ways of doing it? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Is your rectangle always the center-most object in the image? Is it always the smallest object? You might look into other properties returned by `regionprops` like `Area`, `BoundingBox` and `Centroid`.

Comment: @beaker thank you,I will try it!! And yes it is the smallest object and center-most object as well!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your image *A* has size of 36x52x3, where 3 are for red, green and blue.
So if you replace

```
B = im2bw(A);
```

with following code:

```
a = double(A); % in case it is integer type
a = a(:,:,2) - a(:,:,1) - a(:,:,3); % try to find green only
B = im2bw(a); % you may need to set level based on image data type
```

you should get what you want.

Comment: Thank you. But Im not getting the dimensions of the rectangle alone. It includes the white regions on the left an right side too.

Comment: You are right. The yellow part has green, so it is picked up too. Try my updated answer, and you may need to set *level* (the 2nd input to *im2bw* if needed.